# Tools for Monitoring Steal Time (st)

Tags: xen, top, virtualization

We're running on a virtual "dedicated" server, which should, in theory, mean that we're the only guys on the server.  In practice.... I'm thinking we might not be.

[image]

Notice that although it looks like we're killing our machine, "Steal time" is at 71%

I'm taking statistics on load and I was disappointed that this stat didn't show up in my graphs.  Are there any tools which monitor this which might be able to help?

---

Additional information:

We're running 4 cores, model:

```
# grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz
```

Comment: Virtual dedicated? In case of XEN they would need to pin dedicated cores for dedicated use in your VM. Looks like your provider has overbooked CPUs by a unfair amout. What does he say to this?

Comment: still waiting for their support guys to get back to us.  Supposedly the "virtual dedicated" concept was to give us a real metal server.  It makes scaling, backup and a few other things easier.  This is not the first support ticket regarding our load problems, so if this turns out to be the cause, I'll be rather... unhappy.

Comment: How many vCPUs have you got and what type of CPU is reported in `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo|sort -u`? If this really a dedicated server then there is something eating up CPU-time on the Dom0. OR they gave you more vCPUs than are available in the Dom0.

Comment: I added some info about the cores above in the question.  These bursts of st are short-lived, but they cause a big impact to our server.

Comment: According to the [Intel-SPEC](http://ark.intel.com/products/36503/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7500-%283M-Cache-2_93-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29) this seems to be a single processor with two cores and hyper-threading enabled.

Comment: The spec is right, but does it matter?  dual core hyperthreading v. quad-core still show up as 4 CPUs.  Should Xen only allocate us 2 CPUs?

Comment: Unless this is a momentary outlier, it looks like your isp is lieing to you and they are, in fact, running other cpu heavy vms on this machine, or there is something configured very wrong that is causing dom0 to hog a lot of cpu time.

Comment: SuSE recommends to reserve two cores solely for the Dom0 so it can do all IO-handling without bothering other VMs. In my eyes that would only be necessary for systems with stolen time in the DomUs AND heavy IO traffic. I wanted to know if your provider assigned more vCPUs than logical cores - like assign 4 vCPUs while only 2 logical CPUs are available in the Dom0 - that would explain "stolen", too (and is a pretty braindead idea - but possible in XEN).

Comment: The root cause of this one turned out to be that the ISP had the VM incorrectly configured.   The guest was being told it had more cores than it actually did.  This seemed to cause havoc with the scheduling.  The ISP couldn't provide intelligent tech support, but we were able to "prove" the problem by disabling odd-numbered cores in /proc.   Never a problem since.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're question is well defined, but you're not giving a lot of information about your environment, how you're currently monitoring or what graphing tools you're using. However, given that SNMP is used pretty much universally for that I'll assume that you're using it and have at least some familiarity with it.

Although (as near as I can tell) the CPU Steal time isn't currently available from snmpd, you can extend it yourself with the `UCD-SNMP-MIB::extOutput` object and `exec` commands.

The easiest way (that I've found) to get the steal time is from `iostat`. Using the following construct we can get *just* the steal time:

```
$ iostat -c | awk 'NR==4 {print $5}'
0.00
```

Therefore, append the following to your snmpd.conf:

```
exec cpu_steal_time /usr/bin/iostat -c | /usr/bin/awk 'NR==4 {print $5}'
```

(Alternatively you can put the command in a wrapper script and call the wrapper from inside `snmpd.conf`.)

Each `exec` call in `snmpd.conf` is indexed starting from 1. So if you only have a single exec statement then you'll want to poll `UCD-SNMP-MIB::extOutput.1`. If this is the 5th exec statement then poll `UCD-SNMP-MIB::extOutput.5`, etc.

The numeric OID for `UCD-SNMP-MIB::extOutput` is `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.101` so if you're at index 1 it would be `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.101.1`, and index 5 would be `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.101.5`, etc.

You then create a graph polling that SNMPD OID of type gauge, ranging from 0–100. This should give you some pretty graphs.

Comment: Great answer. How often will these statics be gathered? Just during poll, or is there a way like in the RMON-MIB that will record values without external poll?

Comment: I believe it would pull this each time the `snmpd` is queried for that OID.

Comment: If iostat is not installed:
top -bn1 | sed -nr '3s/.*,//gp'

Answer (score 10):

`sar -u` might be helpful in your case. sar is normally part of the **sysstat**-package.

Comment: I wish I could set more than one answer as the accepted answer.  Both answers have been very useful :-)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The most upvoted answer is great, but at this time it isn't fully-working: **net-snmp** loses pipe in `exec` call, so this should be looking like this

```
extend-sh cpu_steal_time /usr/bin/iostat -c 1 1 | /usr/bin/awk '!/%user|Linux|^$/ {print $5}'
```

And the result will be visible under `nsExtendOutput1Table`:

```
# snmpwalk localhost NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Table
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."cpu_steal_time" = STRING: 0.60
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutputFull."cpu_steal_time" = STRING: 0.60
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutNumLines."cpu_steal_time" = INTEGER: 1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendResult."cpu_steal_time" = INTEGER: 0
```

where `nsExtendOutput1Line` oid is .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1:

```
snmpwalk localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."cpu_steal_time" = STRING: 0.60
```