# High cpu steal on Core 0 of KVM

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

In one of my KVM setups I am seeing high CPU stealing for Core 0 of both the guests. I have gone through saveral web results related to cpu steal but no were core steal is explained.

If I take average it doesn't look that bad. 40/8 ~ 5%. But for single core  its very high.

`Threads: 815 total,   4 running, 811 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 18.4 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 35.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  6.4 si, 39.2 st
%Cpu1  : 38.6 us,  6.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 48.5 id,  5.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 31.0 us, 20.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 47.0 id,  2.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 22.0 us, 14.0 sy,  4.0 ni, 48.0 id, 12.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 31.7 us, 18.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 48.5 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 41.0 us, 13.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 46.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  8.1 us,  7.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 35.3 us, 24.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 39.2 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  :  3.0 us,  5.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  :  5.9 us,  6.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 :  6.1 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 : 10.4 us, 13.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 24.0 id, 52.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 : 50.0 us, 10.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 48966980 total, 13622884 free, 25813260 used,  9530836 buff/cache`

I have done cpu isolation in the host and there are only two guest VM per host.
cat /proc/cmdline

`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/VolGrp-Vol1 ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VolGrp/Vol1 rd.lvm.lv=VolGrp/Vol0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 isolcpus=2-15,18-31 nohz_full=2-15,18-31 rcu_nocbs=2-15,18-31 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 intel_pstate=disable nosoftlockup=0 audit=0 mce=ignore_ce transparent_hugepage=never`

Also same cores are not shared between two VMs
From virsh dumpxml

VM1

`<vcpu placement='static' cpuset='2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20,22,24,26,28,30'\>13</vcpu>`

VM2

`<vcpu placement='static' cpuset='3,5,7,9,11,13,15,19,21,23,25,27,29,31'\>13</vcpu>`

Host NUMA information:

`NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
 NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31`

Host OS: CentOS 7.4

Guest OS: CentOS 7.4

qemu KVM version:  1.5.3

Any suggestions who to find why i have such a high steal value ?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing oversubscription of your virtualised environment e.g. collectively, the VMs on that host are trying to use more CPU resources than the host has.

If you pinning a couple of VMs to a single CPU, so much the better for debugging, you will be able to point out quickly for the culprit. Watch out for CPU/I/O/memory, often lack of resources on one influence the others.

see [iostat - What does the 'steal' field mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264958/iostat-what-does-the-steal-field-mean/264965)

Taken from that question:

> As per man vmstat:
>
> ```
> st: Time stolen from a virtual machine. Prior to Linux 2.6.11, unknown.
> ```
>
> ....
>
> It’s the time the hypervisor scheduled something else to run instead
>   of something within your VM. This might be time for another VM, or for
>   the Hypervisor host itself. If no time were stolen, this time would be
>   used to run your CPU workload or your idle thread.

PS Over the long term, I do advise not pinning specific VMs to specific CPUs as a global strategy. The hypervisor is capable of taking better decisions than yourself when distributing the CPU resources/load.